# Unbinding an array on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is the scenario. I have two scope arrays with predefined values which are "sorts" and "preSort" and they are not binded together. I have buttons that adds values to the "sorts" array and a reset button. The reset button is clicked so that the value of the the "sorts" array will be the same as  the value of "preSort" array. However the problem is, when I click the reset. The two arrays are now binded. I wish to be not binded after clicking the reset button

Please see the following code:

```js
 function isInArray(value, array) { 
        return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
  }
  function ascendingArrayList(value, array){
   new_value = value.replace('-', '')
   index = array.indexOf(value);
   // alert(index);
   // Conditional statement is to make sure that it does not delete anything if field did not make any sorting yet
   // Comment the conditional to enable single sorting for each field
   if(index != -1){
    array.splice(index, 1);
   }
   array.push(new_value);
   return array;
  }
  function descendingArrayList(value, array){
   new_value = value.replace('-', '')
   index = array.indexOf(new_value);
   // Conditional statement is to make sure that it does not delete anything if field did not make any sorting yet
   // Comment the conditional to enable single sorting for each field
   if(index != -1){
    array.splice(index, 1);
   }
   array.push(value);
   return array;
  }


     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider) {
   // Change template tags
      $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
      $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });

  app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   $scope.sorts = ["rank_order"];
   $scope.preSort = ["rank_order"];
   $scope.tableHeaders = [
    {'name': 'No.', 'field':'-rank_order'},
    {'name': 'Code'},
    {'name': 'Description'},
    {'name': 'Department', 'field':'-rank_department'},
    {'name': 'Type', 'field':'-rank_type'},
    {'name': 'Updated By', 'field':'-updated_by__bio__user_code'},
    {'name': 'Date Updated', 'field':'-date_updated'},
   ];
   $scope.reset = function(){
    
    $scope.sorts = $scope.preSort;
   }

   $scope.sort = function(field){

       if(isInArray(field, $scope.sorts)){
        $scope.sorts = ascendingArrayList(field, $scope.sorts)
       }else{
        // $scope.sorts.push(field);
        $scope.sorts = descendingArrayList(field, $scope.sorts)
       }
   }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
 <table border="1px">
    <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="x in tableHeaders">
   [[x.name]] <span ng-if="x.field" ng-click="sort(x.field, $event)"><u>Click to Sort</u></span>
    </th>
  </tr>
   </table>
    preSort:[[ preSort ]] ------------------------------- sorts: [[ sorts ]]
   <br />
   <button ng-click="reset()">Click to reset</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: try this  $scope.reset = function(){
           $scope.sorts = ["rank_order"];
        }

Comment: angular.copy does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `angular.copy`.

```
    $scope.reset = function(){

        $scope.sorts = angular.copy($scope.preSort);
    }
```

For more info, see [AngularJS angular.copy API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 1):

Inside `$scope.reset()` you have to use something to clone the array instead of doing an assignment between scope variables.

You can use for example [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)'s _.map functions

```
$scope.sorts = _.map($scope.preSorts, _.clone)
```